# Logstash conditional output to elasticsearch (index per filebeat hostname)

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I have several web servers with filebeat installed and I want to have multiple indices per host.

My current configuration looks as

```
input {
  beats {
    ports => 1337
  }
}

filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}"}
  }
  geoip {
    source => "clientip"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
  if [beat][hostname] == "luna"
  {
         hosts => "10.0.1.1:9200"
         manage_template => true
         index => "lunaindex-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
         document_type => "apache"
  }
  }
}
```

However the above conf results to

> The given configuration is invalid. Reason: Expected one of #, => at
>   line 22, column 6 (byte 346)

which is where the if statement takes place. Any help?

I would like to have the above in a nested format as

```
if [beat][hostname] == "lina"
{
index = lina
}
else if [beat][hostname] == "lona"
{
index = lona
}
```

etc. Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access any inner field you have to enclosed it with %{}.

Try this

```
%{[beat][hostname]}
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38500149/access-nested-json-field-in-logstash) for more explanations.

**UPDATE:**

Using %{[beat][hostname]} with == will not work, try

```
if "lina" in [beat][hostname]{
    index = lina
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it didnt work - I am still getting the same error

Comment: I tried the following
"output {
     if %{[beat][hostname]} == "test1" {
     elasticsearch {
     hosts => "10.0.1.1:9200"
     manage_template => true
     index => "testing-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
     document_type => "apache"
     }
  }
}"

Still comes with an error in the if statement

Answer (score 6):

The thread is old but hopefully somebody will find this useful. Plugin definitions don't allow conditionals in them and hence the error. The conditional must include the entire definition like below. Also, see the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#conditionals) for details.

```
output {
    if [beat][hostname] == "luna" {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => "10.0.1.1:9200"
            manage_template => true
            index => "lunaindex-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
            document_type => "apache"
        }
    } else{
       elasticsearch {
            // alternate configuration
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution can be :

Define in each of your filebeat configuration file, in the prosperctor section define the document type :

> document_type: luna

And in your pipeline conf file, check the type field

> if[type]=="luna"

Hope this help.

Comment: This wouldnt work cause in my case both types are 'apache'

Comment: if you dont want to change the type, you can add a tag as following :

in filebeat configuration file, in the prospector section add : **tags: ["luna"]** 
In your logstash pipeline check the tag :  **if "luna" in [tags]**

Comment: thats a nice idea actually -- will give it a go soon

Comment: Great! So it was useful ?